# Not able go to other view from callback

Tags: ios, swiftui

In the code below, why doesn't it take me to the AppView() page when onDismiss is called? I basically have a network call in LinkController that is logging someone in and then I need to progress to a different view once finished.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showLink = false
    @State private var publicToken: String?
    @State private var metadata: [String : Any]?

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            self.showLink = true
        }) { Text("Add Account") }
            .sheet(isPresented: self.$showLink,
                onDismiss: {
                    // why doesn't this work
                    AppView(publicToken: self.publicToken!)
                }, content: {
                    LinkController(publicToken: self.$publicToken, metadata: self.$metadata)
                })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            self.showLink = true
        }) { Text("Add Account") }
            .sheet(isPresented: self.$showLink,
                onDismiss: {
                    if self.publicToken != nil { self.goHome() }
                }, content: {
                    LinkController(publicToken: self.$publicToken, metadata: self.$metadata)
                })


    }

    func goHome() {
        if let window = UIApplication.shared.windows.first {
            window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: AppView(publicToken: publicToken!))
            window.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }
    }
```